# GDAL Tiling, Missing Tiles

Tags: python, gdal, tiles, tiling

i have used gdal2tiles.py for tiling about 100 tiff tiles which i have generated virtual dataset with gdalbuildvrt for my 1:250.000 scaled maps...

everything goes well from 15 to 11, but when it comes to 10, the following parts was not generated from top to downs.(I gave a picture of the sample below) and it finishes at 70 like this ...50...60...70...

i think gdal dont get extent of map for making it small(resolution) for zoom levels.

is there anyone meet this problem or somebody help me about this trouble?

**Example Result:**

Black areas indicate regions which wasnt rendered.

[image: tileerror]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When GDAL finishes like that, it means it's crashed, which would explain your missing areas. It's possible it's just run out of memory, or that opening one of the TIFFs has caused it to go haywire. Because it's a Python script, it's possible an exception has been thrown by GDAL, and caught silently by the script. Check your memory usage as it runs to see if you get a rapid rise in usage at some point.

Try running it on a subset of your source images, and then running it again on those results.